# Is there an Excel Formula which returns at WHAT POINT in an active string of data, data changes form (from 1 to 2)?

Tags: excel

Folks, REALLY would appreciate help <3

If I have the following strings of data in Excel (3 examples below) where data is coded as 1 or 2, does anyone know an Excel formula which can tell me WHEN in the sequence the data switches from 1 to 2? i.e., in the example, at the 4th, 2nd, and 8th point/column along, out of the 9.

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2. 

1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2.
```

So far, I am able to use the following formula (see below) to see IF there is a change from 1 to 2 in the sequence, but now need to know WHEN the change occurs.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("21",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,[data range of a row]))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Comment: it looks like you are just looking for the first change between 1,1,1,1, and 2,2,2,2,2. In that case it would be enough to look for the index of the first 2 in the row. And I think ```=XMATCH(2,A3:G3) ``` would work for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Find()` function actually return the position of the target string.
Instead of `IF(ISERROR(...`, use

```
=iferror(FIND("21",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,[data range of a row])),FALSE)
```

and better link the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787241/identify-rows-where-a-specific-pattern-change-occurs/61787691#61787691) for system integrity purpose.

Comment: Hey Oliver, it worked! Thank you, you are fantastic <3

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the number '2' by using:

```
=ROUNDUP(FIND(2,A1)/3,0)
```

[image]